# Get array of JSON column and check on duplicates / VueJS

Tags: json, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I have a JSON file with many different columns as you can see below (I'm using BootstrapVue).

I want to get an array of one column and I want to filter it on duplicates.

My JSON file:

```json
[
    { "Number": 111, "Input1": "Good morning", "Input2": "Test1" },
    { "Number": 222, "Input1": "Hello", "Input2": "Test2" },
    { "Number": 333, "Input1": "Good morning", "Input2": "Test2" },
    { "Number": 444, "Input1": "Ciao", "Input2": "Test2" },
    { "Number": 555, "Input1": "Hey", "Input2": "Test2" },
    { "Number": 666, "Input1": "Hey", "Input2": "Test2" }
]
```

I try to filter column 2 (Input1) and check duplicates - so the final array should look like this:

```
data():{
  return {
    Input1 = [{text: 'Good morning'}, {text: 'Hello'}, {text: 'Ciao'}, {text: 'Hey'}]
  }
}
```

I need it like this because it's for b-form-select fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it a computed property that loops through all values, takes only the `Input1` value, then filter duplicates and finally map all to have the correct format.

Something like:

```js
data: function(){
  return {
    selected: null,
    the_json: [
      { "Number": 111, "Input1": "Good morning", "Input2": "Test1" },
      { "Number": 222, "Input1": "Hello", "Input2": "Test2" },
      { "Number": 333, "Input1": "Good morning", "Input2": "Test2" },
      { "Number": 444, "Input1": "Ciao", "Input2": "Test2" },
      { "Number": 555, "Input1": "Hey", "Input2": "Test2" },
      { "Number": 666, "Input1": "Hey", "Input2": "Test2" }
    ]
  };
},
computed: {
  filtered_from_json: function() {
    let arr = this.the_json.map((v) => v.Input1); // Take only the `Input1` value
    return arr
      .filter((v, idx) => arr.indexOf(v) == idx) // Discard values that are present already (= lower index)
      .map((v) => { return {text: v, value: v}; }); // Transform value into object with property `text` of value
  }
},
```

And [use](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-select) like so: `<b-form-select v-model="selected" :options="filtered_from_json"></b-form-select>`

Comment: thank you! but how can I reference it to my select form?

Comment: I'm not familiar with b-form-select, but in regular Vue it's something like `<option v-for="item, idx in filtered_from_json" :key="idx" :value="item.text">{{ item.text }}</option>`.

Comment: Oh, according to [this documentation](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-select) it should be `:options="filtered_from_json"`. BUT: the return objects should also have a `value` property!
So `return {text: v};` becomes `return {text: v, value: v};`

Comment: I edited my answer to include the specific use.